Need help comparing a premade string to a user input string
The assignment is to make a console that accepts commands, but I can't even properly figure out comparing the string to parse the command.
.data 
cmdline: .asciiz "> "
helpline: .asciiz "> Commands:\n> help - displays available commands\n> echo - returns text inputted after command\n> exit - exits program\n>\n"
helpcomp: .asciiz "help"
echocomp: .asciiz "echo"
exitcomp: .asciiz "exit"
noRecog: .asciiz "> Command not recognized\n> Input 'help' for a list of commands\n>\n"
tempText: .asciiz "echo found\n"
buffer: .space 21
buffersize: .word 20
.text 

j cmdLoop

cmdLoop:
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, cmdline
    syscall
    
    la      $s2, buffer
    move    $t2, $s2
    syscall
    
    move   $a0,$t2
        la          $a1, buffersize
        li          $v0, 8
        syscall
        
        j help
        
 help:
    la $s3, helpcomp
    move $t2, $s3
compareHelp:

        lb      $t2,($s2)                   # get next char from str1
    lb      $t3,($s3)                   # get next char from str2
    bne     $t2,$t3,compareExit               # are they different? if yes, fly

    beq     $t2,$zero,helpExecute             # at EOS? yes, fly (strings equal)

        addi    $s2,$s2,1                   # point to next char
        addi    $s3,$s3,1                   # point to next char
        j       compareHelp
        
helpExecute:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, helpline
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    
compareExit:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, tempText
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

Here's the MIPS code I have right now, and here's what I want it to do written in java
public class Console {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("> ");
        
        while(true) {
            String command = input.nextLine();
            
            if(command.contains("help")) {
                System.out.print("Commands:"
                        + "\nhelp - displays available commands"
                        + "\necho - prints the text inputted    right after echo"
                        + "\nexit - quits out of the program"
                        + "\n> ");
            } else if (command.contains("echo")) {
                String echo = command.substring(5, command.length());
                System.out.println(echo);
                System.out.print("> ");
            } else if (command.contains("exit")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        input.close();

    }

}

I've tried (and failed) using stuff I've found online, but they're built for both or neither of the strings to be inputted by the user.

You have some Java code to compare with, which is a good start.  However, you're using some helper functions in Java that you'll have to write yourself  (not necessarily as functions, but the general "functionality" of them) in assembly.  So, proceed in that direction, eliminating use of those in the Java version (i.e. do it in Java without using string.contains), then you'll really have something that will translate directly to assembly language.

To put it into other words, you need an algorithms for .contains, and you don't have to develop that from scratch in assembly if you have done so in Java first (and that's much easier).  Following this approach, your assembly questions will be more limited, i.e. how do I do this same loop in assembly, or how do I do this same array reference in assembly?
